# Does child processes garbage collector block the parents process main thread?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

If you start a child process with the System.Diagnostics.Process class and this child process allocates garbage, will the garbage collection of this garbage happen only in the child process?

Comment: You can't allocate garbage.  Yes, GC is performed per-process.

Comment: @HansPassant - I think he means "accumulate" garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Each process is distinct and behaves independently in terms of garbage collection regardless they are parent or child.